# SQL: How to find records between 2 dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

The dates are in Y2K date string format

eg) `1120104` = `20120104`

Running SQL Server 2008

Comment: What the heck date is 1120104?

Comment: What date does your example represent?

Comment: first digit = after year 2000
then 2 digits for year, month, day

Comment: Y2K format is CYYMMDD where C is Century and is optional

Comment: 4th Jan 2012 in this example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First advice: store the dates as data type date or datetime so that you can actually search on them.

If you don't want that, you need to convert the strings to date first so that you can search on them:

```
where convert(date, my_nasty_string_column_with_dates) between @a and @b
```

This is a perf problem because the query will never be able to seek on an index.

Comment: OK. I can store the dates as data type date. How can I search between 2 dates in this case? Hope this doesn't screw up the Q&A process:)

Comment: In that case just leave out the conversion and use `between` directly. Or use something like `col >= @a AND col <= @b`. Just like that, no magic involved.

Answer (score 3):

Well I agree with @usr, first, stop storing dates this way.

If you can't, then add a computed column (which you could even persist and/or index):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ADD RealDate 
 AS CONVERT(DATE, RIGHT(col, 6), 12);
```

If you can't do that, then create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.SmarterView
AS
  SELECT /* other columns, */ 
    RealDate = CONVERT(DATE, RIGHT(col, 6), 12)
  FROM dbo.MyTable;
```

Then:

```
SELECT ... FROM dbo.MyTable -- or dbo.SmarterView
  WHERE RealDate >= @Start 
  AND RealDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @End);
```

Open-ended ranges are far better than `BETWEEN` - calculating the end of the month sucks, especially in February, and especially if you have any potential for date/time data type changes. See:

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

If you have dates in the 1900s, then it is slightly more involved:

```
CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(CHAR(2), 19 + CONVERT(INT, LEFT(col, 1))) + RIGHT(col, 6), 112);
```

In any case, it's irrelevant, since the OP stated they will store it correctly as `DATE`.

Comment: And thanks to the computed col you can now index on the date. +1

Comment: Will not work with 1900's dates. You're scrapping the century.

Comment: @InfinitePossiblities thanks, assumed all dates were >= 2000.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to compare at Y2K date with another with simple equality checks. If you want to convert the Y2K to `DateTime` then you need to add 19000000 then convert it like this example:

```
DECLARE @Y2KDate INT
SET @Y2KDate = 1120104
DECLARE @DateTime DateTime
SET @DateTime = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), @Y2KDate + 19000000), 112) 
PRINT @DateTime
```

Prints the following output

> ```
> 1120104
> 20120104
> Jan  4 2012 12:00AM
> ```